# Problem with simple select query to find dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I use simple query to get dates of contract for a person:

```
SELECT 
    [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa],
    IsNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], GETDATE()) AS 'KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa'
FROM   [BazaZarzadzanie].[dbo].[KlienciPortfeleUmowy]
WHERE  [PortfelID] = 3
```

This is what I get:

```
KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa  KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa
2005-11-28 00:00:00.000    2008-07-22 00:00:00.000
2008-07-23 00:00:00.000    2010-03-09 15:45:42.457
```

Client signs a contract which started at 2005-11-28 and then appendix was signed so his currenct contract ended 2008-07-22 and new one started at 2008-07-23 and lasts till today (NULL that was converted to current time). There can be clients with many many more appendix but it all goes like that.

`My question is`: How do i get contract that is/was active between lets say 2008-04-01 - 2008-06-30? It's possible that the client between that period will have 2 or even 5 appendix so it should return all of them.

Also I am not sure if it's needed to use IsNull? Maybe there's a better way for this so i could skip IsNull usage and entering current date as replacement.

EDIT:

I thought that solution from marc_s solved it but it seems it didn't:

```
SELECT 
    [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa],
    [KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa]
FROM   [BazaZarzadzanie].[dbo].[KlienciPortfeleUmowy]
 WHERE  [PortfelID] = 3 AND 
 [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] <= '2008-07-01' AND IsNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], '99991231') >= '2008-09-30'
```

It return 0 dates for the period of 2008-07-01 to 2008-09-30 when it should return both:

```
2005-11-28 00:00:00.000    2008-07-22 00:00:00.000
2008-07-23 00:00:00.000    NULL
```

As the client had contract in both times.

EDIT2:

I've tested proposed 2 queries. First one for dates (20080401 - 20080630) as in example below returns 1 row for 1st query (expected), returns 0 rows for 2nd query (not expected).

```
 SELECT [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa],
    IsNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], '99991231') AS 'KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa'
  FROM   [BazaZarzadzanie].[dbo].[KlienciPortfeleUmowy]     
  WHERE  [PortfelID] = 3  
  AND [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] <= '20080401' AND IsNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], '99991231') >= '20080630'

 SELECT 
 [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa],
 [KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa]
 FROM   
[BazaZarzadzanie].[dbo].[KlienciPortfeleUmowy]
 WHERE  
[PortfelID] = 3 AND 
-- either: start date is sometime between the two dates
([KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] BETWEEN '20080401' AND '20080630'
-- or: end date is sometime between the two dates        
  OR 
  ISNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], GETDATE()) BETWEEN '20080401' AND '20080630')
```

Second test for dates '20080701' to '20080930' shows for first query 0 results (not expected), and for 2nd query 2 rows (expected).

```
 SELECT [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa],
    IsNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], '99991231') AS 'KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa'

 FROM   [BazaZarzadzanie].[dbo].[KlienciPortfeleUmowy]

WHERE  [PortfelID] = 3  

 AND [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] <= '20080701' AND IsNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], '99991231') >= '20080930'


SELECT 
[KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa],
[KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa]

FROM   
[BazaZarzadzanie].[dbo].[KlienciPortfeleUmowy]
WHERE  
[PortfelID] = 3 AND 
-- either: start date is sometime between the two dates
([KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] BETWEEN '20080701' AND '20080930'
-- or: end date is sometime between the two dates        
  OR 
  ISNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], GETDATE()) BETWEEN '20080701' AND '20080930')
```

EDIT3:

Using COMBINED solution from both examples it works for both dates. But won't it blow back at me for diffrent client dates? Any Ideas?

```
 SELECT [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa]
     , ISNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], GETDATE()) AS 'KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa'
 FROM   [BazaZarzadzanie].[dbo].[KlienciPortfeleUmowy]
WHERE  [PortfelID] = 3
  AND 
  (
  ([KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] BETWEEN '20080401' AND '20080630'
   OR ISNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], GETDATE()) BETWEEN '20080401' AND '20080630')
   OR ([KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] <= '20080401' AND IsNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], '99991231') >= '20080630')

  )

SELECT [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa]
 , ISNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], GETDATE()) AS 'KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa'
 FROM   [BazaZarzadzanie].[dbo].[KlienciPortfeleUmowy]
WHERE  [PortfelID] = 3
  AND 
  (
  ([KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] BETWEEN '20080701' AND '20080930'
   OR ISNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], GETDATE()) BETWEEN '20080701' AND '20080930')
   OR ([KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] <= '20080701' AND IsNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], '99991231') >= '20080930')

  )
```

Comment: @Madboy: actually, my code is correct, in your sample, no rows will be selected. The first row is eliminated since it's end date (2008-07-22) is **NOT** >= '2008-09-30' - ok? The second rows is removed from the query result since it's start date (2008-07-23) is **NOT** <= '2008-07-01' - so I think this is correct that none of those rows are returned. Maybe you need to formulate the condition differently.

Comment: @Modboy: see my update - with a bit of re-formulating the query condition, you should get what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for update. Doesn't work yet the way i would expect it to.

Comment: for query #1, see my first comment here - that's still the same problem. The condition you have just simply removes both expected rows - check it out!!

Comment: @marc_s: well i do have to get what i need to get. I need to give sql 2 dates. And i need to get back to me how many contracts were legit for that period and what dates it had. 3rd edit seems to work but it's not something i am 100% sure about. Your 1st query works for first example, 2nd query works for 2nd example. If i merge both of your examples into one it works fine. But will it blow back, i have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: How do i get contract
>   that is/was active between lets say
>   2008-04-01 - 2008-06-30? It's possible
>   that the client between that period
>   will have 2 or even 5 appendix so it
>   should return all of them.

Basically that means:

- the start date of your contract must be on or before 2008-04-01
- the end date of your contract must be on or after 2008-06-30

So you need something like:

```
SELECT 
    (list of fields)
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE
    StartDate <= '20080401' AND EndDate >= '20080630'
```

(or whatever that will be in Polish :-)

You won't need ISNULL, unless one of your dates could be NULL (e.g. the EndDate = NULL means: contract is valid until revoked).

In that case, do something like:

```
SELECT 
    (list of fields)
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE
    StartDate <= '20080401' AND ISNULL(EndDate, '99991231') >= '20080630'
```

If the `EndDate` is NULL, pretend it's the 31st of December 9999 - that should do for the next couple thousand years :)

**UPDATE:**
For your update, try this query here:

```
SELECT 
    [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa],
    [KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa]
FROM   
    [BazaZarzadzanie].[dbo].[KlienciPortfeleUmowy]
WHERE  
    [PortfelID] = 3 AND 
    -- either: start date is sometime between the two dates
    ([KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] BETWEEN '20080701' AND '20080930'
    -- or: end date is sometime between the two dates        
      OR 
      ISNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], GETDATE()) BETWEEN '20080701' AND '20080930')
```

Does that return the results you're expecting??

Comment: I really should get some rest. Having difficulties with simple stuff like that :/

Comment: But as you can see 2 other guys made same mistake like i did using between on both dates start and end date and that approach was returning 0 results! So I'm not that bad ;)

Comment: marc_s i think it doesn't work for date '2008-07-01' to '2008-09-30' when i passed those dates no results were returned (for the dates mentioned in question).

Comment: +1 as MadBoy pointed your solution to me as working. Thanks for the lesson! ;P

Comment: @Madboy: be careful to use the ISO-8601 format: `YYYYMMDD` - no dashes or anything! otherwise, you language and regioanl settings might cause problems. Use '20080701' and '20080930' - does that work? Also: are the contract by any chance starting or ending on those very dates? Then maybe the time portion of the DATETIME of the contract StartDate/EndDate might cause problems, too

Comment: In my testing it doesn't. It worked for the first try, but i then put this inside my C# app and there it builds values proper way. Just to be sure i've tested this with your last advice and same no luck. It's obvious thou 20080723 isn't smaller then 20080701.

Comment: if i test that on [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] <= '2008-07-01' 
and test that [KlienciUmowaDataKoncowa] >= '2008-09-30' it won't match this:
2005-11-28 00:00:00.000    2008-07-22 00:00:00.000
and it should.

Comment: Unfortunetly it works only for dates i just posted, but it doesn't work for the earlier date. It returns 2 rows for '20080701' to '20080930' but it doesn't return any row for '20080401' to '20080630' while it returned 1 before with your old example. I'm updating main post now to provide you what i've used.

Comment: See my Edit2. Shows 2 tests. 2 diffrent results :(

Comment: I've combined 2 queries of yours into 1. It seems to work (EDIT 3) but i am afraid it may blow back at me at some point. Do you think the example is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work.  If not then can you be a little more clear and give us some examples rows for what should and shouldn't be returned.

```
SELECT 
    [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa],
    IsNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], GETDATE()) AS 'KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa'
FROM   [BazaZarzadzanie].[dbo].[KlienciPortfeleUmowy]
WHERE  [PortfelID] = 3
AND KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] <= '2008-04-01'
AND IsNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], GETDATE()) >= '2008-06-30'
```

Or you could do

```
SELECT 
    [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa],
    IsNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], GETDATE()) AS 'KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa'
FROM   [BazaZarzadzanie].[dbo].[KlienciPortfeleUmowy]
WHERE  [PortfelID] = 3
AND KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] <= '2008-04-01'
AND ([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa] >= '2008-06-30'
  OR [KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa] IS NULL)
```

Finally it sounds like you might want all contracts for clients that had at least 1 active Contract between those dates.  If that is the case do this:

```
SELECT 
    [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa],
    IsNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], GETDATE()) AS 'KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa'
FROM   [BazaZarzadzanie].[dbo].[KlienciPortfeleUmowy]
WHERE  [PortfelID] = 3
AND <Client_ID> IN
    (SELECT 
        <Client_ID>
    FROM   [BazaZarzadzanie].[dbo].[KlienciPortfeleUmowy]
    WHERE  [PortfelID] = 3
    AND KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] <= '2008-04-01'
    AND IsNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], GETDATE()) >= '2008-06-30')
```

Comment: Altough you posted a lot of information marc_s was correct (just like your first solution) and he was first. Thanks for ideas for other stuff. I had problem with it because for some reason i was trying to use BETWEEN all the time just like 2 other guys did in here and it was not working ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand your question, I guess you could use something looking like so:

```
SELECT  
    [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa], 
    CASE WHEN [KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa] IS NULL THEN GETDATE() ELSE [KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa] END AS 'KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa' 
FROM   [BazaZarzadzanie].[dbo].[KlienciPortfeleUmowy] 
WHERE  [PortfelID] = 3 
    AND [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] BETWEEN @ContractDateStart AND @ContractDateEnd
```

Where @ContractDateStart and @ContractDateEnd are the parameterized values contract date start and date end respectively of your query.

Comment: This is the problem. When you use it like that it won't return anything. I used it before and it didn't work correctly.

Comment: It's because [KlienciUmowydataPoczatkowa] is not necessary between those dates. It should return 2005-11-28 00:00:00.000    2008-07-22 00:00:00.000 while if you do between it won't match anything.

Comment: Perhaps not considering the [KlienciUmowydataPoczatkowa] column then within your query. Just consider the [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] column to be within the period parameterized by @ContractDateStart and @ContractDateEnd?

Comment: No, it won't work with BETWEEN. Lets say i want to search for '2008-04-01' till '2008-06-30' period. if you put that in BETWEEN for [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] it won't return 2005-11-28 00:00:00.000 2008-07-22 00:00:00.000 as '2005-11-28' doesn't match the start date, neither does 2008-07-22 match end date. and as you can see this contract is valid for dates i mentioned. Check marc_s solution which is simple and it works.

Comment: Thanks MadBoy for taking the time to explain why my solution doesn't work for you! I checked marc_s' solution and upvoted it. You're right, it's pretty simple! =)

Answer (score 0):

This should get all of your rows that either start or end during a period (Notice the variables @StartDate and @EndDate)

```
SELECT [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa]
     , ISNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], GETDATE()) AS 'KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa'
 FROM   [BazaZarzadzanie].[dbo].[KlienciPortfeleUmowy]
WHERE  [PortfelID] = 3
  AND ([KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
   OR ISNULL([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa], GETDATE()) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
```

Comment: This won't work exactly like with Will advice. It returns 0 rows while marc_s returns 1 (correctly)

Comment: It's because [KlienciUmowydataPoczatkowa] is not necessary between those dates. It should return 2005-11-28 00:00:00.000    2008-07-22 00:00:00.000 while if you do between it won't match anything.